# How to get permanent public download url for a google drive file?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, pydrive

I'm using pydrive for a web app, where users add documents from their own drive to the app and other users can download those documents, I was able to do all authentication and get each added document file metadata

At first I used downloadUrl attribute to let user download it, but it's apparently short lived and expires, when users try to download it they get a blank page , I do too, but I didn't have this issue when I first got the url, it's after around 2 days from getting that url .

I would like to know how can I get a permanent public link for download, that other users can use to download added documents please .
Is there any work-around for this ?

Comment: maybe try calling `GetChanges()` on the `GoogleDriveFile` object to see if the download url is updated? If just updating the url periodically is an option.